# Well, it seems that you're using the professional distribution of pimcore which doesn't include any templates / themes or contents

Tags: pimcore

i am not able to see Editor for newly created page in pimcore Admin panel?

below message comes .................>>>

Where can I edit some pages?
Well, it seems that you're using the professional distribution of pimcore which doesn't include any templates / themes or contents, it's designed to start a project from scratch. If you need a jump start please consider using our sample data / boilerplate package which includes everything you need to get started.

.....................>>>>>>>>>>

what settings i have to do?

Comment: not sure but EditmodeListener.php is giving empty string

Comment: tried printing $headHtml .= “\n\n\n\n\n”;
var_dump($headHtml);
line 295 in [EditmodeListener.php]
its showing blank ?Where can I edit some pages?
Well, it seems that you're using the professional distribution of pimcore which doesn't include any templates / themes or contents, it's designed to start a project from scratch. If you need a jump start please consider using our sample data / boilerplate package which includes everything you need to get started.